# Issue with Car ANOVA function in R?

Tags: r

I am running `car` version 2.1.4 and trying to use the `Anova` function to get Wald-based p-values for a power analysis using logistic regression with success/failure setup. If I run the following simple factorial, the function through an error due to 0 residual degrees of freedom but clearly the sample size is extremely large. What am I doing or thinking about this wrong?

Is the problem with the `glm()` call since that likewise says zero residual `df`?

```
X <- matrix(c(100,66566,73,66593,1201,398799,165,66501), 
            nrow = 4,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE)
x_df <- data.frame(premium = c(300,300,500,500),
                   restrict = c(500,2500,500,2500))
x_df$int <- x_df$premium * x_df$restrict
mod <- glm(X~premium+restrict+int, 
           data=x_df,family=binomial)
summary(mod)
car::Anova(mod,type="III","Wald")
```

**ADD #1:**

It appears that the success/failure syntax doesn't work properly. When  I manually expand out the data to ~600,000 rows the fit is the same but the res.df are correct:

```
X<-matrix(c(100,66566,73,66593,1201,398799,165,66501),nrow = 4,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE)
x_df<-data.frame(premium=c(300,300,500,500),restrict=c(500,2500,500,2500))
x_df$int<-x_df$premium*x_df$restrict
mod<-glm(X~premium+restrict+premium*restrict, data=x_df,family=binomial)
summary(mod)
Anova(mod,type = "III",test.statistic = "Wald")

    y=c(rep(1,100),rep(0,66566),rep(1,73),rep(0,66593),rep(1,1201),rep(0,398799),rep(1,165),rep(0,66501))
    premium<-c(rep(300,66666*2),rep(500,1201+398799+165+66501))
    restrict<-c(rep(500,66666),rep(2500,66666),rep(500,1201+398799),rep(2500,165+66501))
    x<-data.frame(y=y,premium=premium,restrict=restrict)           
    mod2<-glm(y~premium+restrict+premium*restrict,data=x,family=binomial)
    summary(mod2)

    Anova(mod2,type = "III",test.statistic = "Wald")
```

Comment: try putting the interaction term in the formula itself,not adding the product in afterwards?

Comment: this is really a statistical problem rather than a programming problem. Voting to close/migrate to CrossValidated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know I think, Is not the success/failure syntax intended to produce the exact same result as expanding out to equivalent number of records?

Answer (score 0):

The residual degrees of freedom is (number of observations)-(number of parameters). You have four observations and four parameters.  I'm not sure what else to say ...

Comment: But the sample size is massive. There are way more than 4 degrees of freedom, right.

Comment: I added an addition. It works fine when expanded out from success/ failure syntax.